# How to 'format cells' with openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I want to format the column cells in my excel sheet using openpyxl to have their numbers decimal places at '0'.

Example Sheet:

```
     B           C
63245634566     NAME
63562341234     NAME
23452345345     NAME
21345234554     NAME
41234123442     NAME
23542345345     NAME
6.24333E+11     NAME
43242334233     NAME
```

Output '***6.24333E+11***'

Wanted Output '***62433323422***'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook( 'so_12387212.xlsx' )
ws = wb[ wb.sheetnames[0] ]
cell11 = ws.cell(1, 1)
cell11.number_format = '0'
wb.save( 'so_12387212.xlsx' )
wb.close()
```

Adapt it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Select all the rows in column B and change it to Numeric.
1- select all the numbers - go to the home tab - change from general to numeric.
2- select all of the numbers - right-click the mouse - select change format - change it to numeric and change it to number.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to write down my complete question i changed it now, but thanks for the answer.