# How to write a dataframe of string values to an excel file as formated numeric values?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

Basically i have a list of string values that are meant to be converted to numeric and printed to an excel sheet. ***Im able to do that already*** ***but i want those values to be printed as "excel number values"***. Here is what i got:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')

listOfValues = ['3913375,45','126179,15','22324,72','26335,28','3699901,34']

df_values = pd.DataFrame({'TOTAL': listOfValues}).apply(pd.to_numeric)

df_values.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='test')

writer.save()
```

My result is:

[Resultant Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1McL.jpg)

But i want it to be printed as numeric values separeted by dots to make it easier to ready, like that:

[What i want to have as result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0k2qb.png)

(The solution i want cannot be printed as strings in the resultant excel, it needs to be numeric values, as if we were using the option "Format as Number (Shift+ctrl+1)" in libreoffice calc).

(Im using Python 3.8.5 and LibreOffice Calc for testing but the result is intended to work in Excel 2016).

Its that possible? Thanks for your help, and sorry about my english!

Comment: `3.913.375,45` is not a numeric value.

Comment: @It_is_Chris In libreoffice calc we have the option "Format as Number (Shift+Ctrl+1)", this makes the value 3913375,45 be printed as 3.913.375,45 for example. This is what i meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57318721/how-to-format-cells-with-openpyxl), it is different, but the answer is the same I think.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('a.xlsx')
ws = wb[wb.sheetnames[0]]
cell11 = ws.cell(1, 1)
cell11.number_format = '#,##0.00'
wb.save('b.xlsx')
wb.close()
```

It works with that format, but it looks like it doesn't work with the `'#.##0,00'` format

Answer (score 0):

Check this https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html

> It is possible to format any other, non date/datetime column data using set_column()

Try changing the formatting example code from this:

```
format1 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#,##0.00'})
```

to this:

```
format1 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#.##0,00'})
```

Comment: I tried this, and it seems to fit what i want as result, but i cant change the engine to xlsxwriter (i need to use openpyxl), because i have other features that depend on that. But this was pretty helpful, I will try find something related to openpyxl, thanks!!